# Python Pulp Solver: How to use compare signs (>= or <=) as variables in equation?

Tags: python, operator-overloading, linear-programming, pulp

Hello I am trying to develop a Python Pulp Linear Programming solver which is not hard-coded but instead takes all input from the user.
I have successfully done the part of objective function but I am having problem with the constraint equation part.

here's a part from my code:

```
sym = input("Enter constraint symbol '>=' or '<=' or '=': ")
op = operatorlookup.get(sym)
prob += lpSum([1*descVar[0] + 1*descVar[2]]) op 200, "Min boys models"
```

The operator lookup class returns the operator used:

```
operatorlookup = {
    '+': operator.add,
    '-': operator.sub,
    '>=': operator.gt,
    '<=': operator.lt,
    '=': operator.eq
}
```

My Problem is how can I assign the symbol `>= or <=` in the equation without getting the syntax error?
A hardcoded constraint would be written like this:

```
prob += lpSum([1*descVar[0] + 1*descVar[2]]) >= 800, "CaloriesMinimum"
```

I cannot use the + or "" because it outputs an error. Any help will be appreciated thank you

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question.  If I strip your code down to something that will run for me, I can enter '>=' or '<=' and have the lookup work correctly.

Comment: The lookup work correctly for me too, but how can I write the symbol in the equation like the one I showed for hardcoding. Take a simple example, we can write 5 >= 2 but how do I save the sign '>=' in a variable op and write it as 5 op 2. It shows syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming

```py
import operator
op = operator.ge
```

Python doesn't interpret variable as operator so `5 op 2` doesn't work. But operators in `operator` module are functions and can be executed as such:

```py
op(5, 2)  # equivalent to 5 >= 2
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html